# Change workstation OU without AD tools in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Right now I have a pushbutton tool, which is basically a fancy GUI that calls the DSMOVE command.

Is it possible to change a workstation account to another OU (in powershell natively) without actually having the AD tools for powershell installed? I do have the syntax to be able to see what OU I am in, but I can't find a way to change it. I'd like to cut out the DSMOVE executable.

The next question would be, how do I?

Answer (score 1):

Without any tools (or error checking, or anything similar):

```
$User = [adsi]'LDAP://CN=BielawB,CN=Users,DC=monad,DC=ps1'
$User.MoveTo('LDAP://OU=Destination,DC=monad,DC=ps1')
```

Obviously, it would be wise to wrap it in some function and add some checking/ error handling.
I've used user object, but that's not different for any other AD object...